# Can outdated systems (e.g. Dell OptiPlex Series) upgrade to newer versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, dual-boot, upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS Precise Pangolin. The update manager creates a window telling me to update to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Trusty Tahr. I'm in a dilemma: updating to Trusty Tahr or not.

My computer is: Dell OptiPlex GX270 SFF (Small-Form-Factor) Europe.

System Specifications:

Processor: Intel Pentium 4 2.40 GHz

RAM: 1024 MB

Hard Disk: Western Digital 60 GB

Operating Systems:Windows 7 Starter 32-bit + Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (Dual Boot, GRUB as boot manager)

Partitioning: Windows(/dev/sda2 - NTFS): 42,62 GB | Ubuntu(/dev/sda5 - ext4): 12,70 GB(7,14 GB used, 5,56 GB free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If doing a clean install is an option, I would suggest looking at 16.04 version of either Lubuntu or [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/). Like 12.04 and 14.04, it is an LTS release, thus supported for the next 4+ years. Lubuntu is generally considered lighter than Xubuntu, but I have no experience with it whatsoever.

I currently have Xubuntu 16.04 installed in one of my computers. Upon boot, without doing anything else, RAM utilization hovers around 220- 250 mb. I was also able to boot the live DVD with as little as 512mb RAM in a virtual environment using VirtualBox. Since you have 1 GB, it would probably run well in your system.

The system will take up around 3+ GB of disk space upon install. You will eventually use up a total of 5-6 GB of disk space after installing common apps.

The XFCE desktop environment which Xubuntu uses is also highly-customizable. You can make it look a bit like unity if you like. It requires a bit of learning curve for new users though.

Comment: I tried Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Xenial Xerus on my Dell PC (Live CD)  and I am happy with the results! The Live CD runs at about (not much difference) the same speed with the Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS Live CD. I'm thinking of installing it a few days after Ubuntu 12.04 support expires (which means that I'm installing it on the 1st or 2nd week of May)  :)

Comment: OK! Thank you for this answer! I'm going to select it as the best!

Comment: I installed Xubuntu 2 days ago and the results are far more better than I expected!!  It's about twice faster than my old Ubuntu 12.04 installation!

Comment: Maybe not the best option.....  This is not intended to say anything or insult you.  I think that Xubuntu is half Ubuntu. It is VERY minimalistic. The Xfce desktop environment isn't at my needs and it reminds me of Mac OS with a Windows 98 theme. I'm thinking of deleting the partition, but last time I did it, it deactivated my Windows 7 Starter. Can you tell me if it's safe or not?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements), you can find the minimum system requirements for Installing Ubuntu Desktop. According to this article, your system meet requirements.

Actually, `Ubuntu 14.04` will be run effectively. Linux itself is not used much hardware resources. But if you run high end application, your system will be slow.

If `Ubuntu 12.04` worked well in current system, `Ubuntu 14.04` will also work well.

Comment: I have provided the minimum requirements [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) in answer. The [link](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) in commented person say for **Recommended** Requirements. If you meet the minimum requirements, your system can be able to run `Ubuntu`.

Comment: Those minimum recommendations are a bit optimistic ;-) I would say that they apply to Lubuntu with the ultra light desktop environment LXDE, but the other flavours of Ubuntu (including standard Ubuntu) need more horsepower and RAM. Your second link with recommended system requirements is more realistic, but still at the low end: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 0):

(San Lin Naing)

### I don't think so... :(

I burned Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS to a DVD and I tested it 2 days ago. It is REAL SLOW. The fade-in/fade-out effect is very slow (to painfully).

After the results, I tested an Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS DVD that I have. It is running fast, like it does when I use it in my PC.

I don't think I'm going to upgrade to or  make a clean install of Trusty Tahr. I was very disappointed. :( ;(

BTW, is there an alternative image of Trusty Tahr? I mean the images that run on systems with less than 300-400 MB of RAM, like the Kubuntu ones.

Comment: I have a Dell Dimension 4600 with a Pentium 4 processor (slightly faster than yours). The newer versions of [standard] Ubuntu want 3-d capability and if the graphics chip/card is lacking this feature, a very show fall-back is used. But the light-weight flavours of Ubuntu: Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu work well, also with the newer versions. I suggest that you try *Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 32-bit* (alias i386). Try it live before installing.

Comment: typing error, written: 'very show fallback', should be; 'very **slow** fallback'

Comment: @sudodus Thanks, but I don't like Lubuntu very much(from what I have seen), especially the desktop environment. I will try Xubuntu 16.04 LTS first on a live CD.

Comment: @sudodus I watched Druaga1's video about Lubuntu and it didn't appeal on me.

Comment: It will probably work well with Xubuntu. Not as fast as Lubuntu but it is important that you like the desktop environment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Lubuntu is much lighter than Ubuntu Desktop and should run well on your machine. The desktop makes fewer demands on the system. Ubuntu Mate may also be worth a try. Normal Ubuntu desktop will run, but slowly.

http://lubuntu.net/

https://ubuntu-mate.org/

Comment: While useful, this is not an answer but a comment - it doesn't answer the question.